# Qt Virtual Keyboard : use specific embedded class or classical?

Tags: c++, qt, embedded

I work with an ARM system, in which I have embedded a version of Qt (qt-everywhere 4.7.4) ; I am currently working on a basic virtual keyboard, 'cause I need Qt to work with a touchscreen.

For now, I send my events with this line :

```
QApplication::sendEvent( widget, event );
```

But I read that there is a *QWSServer* class, especially made for embedded systems, that can launch events too. The thing is, my Qt application is actually quite slow, and I was thinking : is it possible that there is some sort of optimization in *QWSServer* that can improve the perfs ?

The wiki says that the *QWSServer* class dispatch events between clients, but as I only have one touchscreen and one system, there is no need for that... So, do you know more about it ?

Thank you !

Comment: Split the question in two. They are quite unrelated

Comment: New topic for the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254019/qt-send-key-return-and-key-delete-events